# Lambda operator in TableColumn:: setOnEditCommit()

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I use TableView in my code. I want to make cells editable. I found sample on  [Oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) that works excellent

```
lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
    new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
       @Override
       public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
            ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                ).setLastName(t.getNewValue());
        }
    }
);
```

Then I decided to use lambda operator instead of anonymous class.

```
lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person>forTableColumn());
lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
    (CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) -> {
            ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setLastName(t.getNewValue());
    });
```

I got compiler error.

> Incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

But I found this sample on [Oracle site too](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm).

Perhaps this problem is widely known but I didn’t find solution. Why is this code wrong?

Comment: How is `lastNameCol` declared?

Comment: TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");

Comment: I found that if i make 
lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit( (t) -> {
CellEditEvent<Person, String> p = (CellEditEvent<Person, String>)t;

If then I use p it works. But what was wrong I still don’t understand.

Comment: Don't use raw types for the column declaration. You should have `TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");`.You should be able to get rid of the cast to `Person` in the lambda body too.

Comment: oh yes! It really works! Thanks a lot. Please move your answer from comments to answers to make me able to mark question as answered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have declared the table column as a raw type:

```
TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn(...);
```

You should not do this (your IDE really should give you a warning here). Use properly parameterized types:

```
TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>(...);
```

Now, since the compiler knows the type of the column, the lambda will work. Additionally, you can get rid of the cast to `Person`:

```
lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
    (CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) -> {
        t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                .setLastName(t.getNewValue());
});
```

Notice that `CellEditEvent` has a `getRowValue()` that you can use:

```
lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) ->
    t.getRowValue().setLastName(t.getNewValue()));
```

or you can take complete advantage of type inference with

```
lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(t ->
    t.getRowValue().setLastName(t.getNewValue()));
```